# Detecting a KeyUp in an Interrupt Service Routine (IRQ 1)

Tags: c, operating-system, interrupt-handling

I'm writing an operating system and I've already got the key down part working, but I want to detect a key up too.
Here's the code per the minimum reproductible example policy:

```c
static void keyboard_callback(registers_t *regs) {
    uint8_t scancode = port_byte_in(0x60);
    if (scancode > SC_MAX) return;
    if (scancode == KEY_BACKSPACE) {
        backspace(key_buffer);
        kprint_backspace();
    } else if (scancode == KEY_ENTER) {
        kprint("\n");
        user_input(key_buffer);
        key_buffer[0] = '\0';
    } 
    else if (scancode == KEY_LEFT_SHIFT || scancode == KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT)
    {
        shift_mode = 1;
    }
    else {
        char letter = getAscii(scancode, shift_mode);
        shift_mode = 0;
        char str[2] = {letter, '\0'};
        append(key_buffer, letter);
        kprint(str);
    }
    UNUSED(regs);
}
```

I just want to know which port to scan to detect key ups.

Comment: I would imagine it's rather important to know which operating system and/or hardware platform you're working with.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm writing an operating system. I used am i686 toolchain.to compile and link.

Comment: Best to clarify that by editing the question, then. Comments come and go like the wind.